# Erro ao usar Dompdf

Tags: php, pdf

Estou usando o dompdf para gerar pdf e retorna esse **ERRO**:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   Dompdf\mb_internal_encoding() in 
>   C:\Users\adnas\logisticapratica\logisticapratica\php\pdf\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php
>   on line 274

**Código:**

```
<?php
  use Dompdf\Dompdf;
  require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

  $dompdf->load_html('<h1>gerar pdf</h1>');

  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream(
    'teste.pdf',
    array(
      "Attachment" => false
    )
  );
?>;
```

Comment: verifica se no seu php.ini a extensão extension=php_mbstring.dll está comentada

Comment: Se for Linux, dá um php -i ¦ grep mbstring. Se não aparecer nenhuma ocorrência, siga o que o Lucas falou acima.   Veja o post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216274/unable-to-call-the-built-in-mb-internal-encoding-method